# Invalid value undefined for HardhatConfig.networks.mainnet_fork.url - Expected a value of type string

Tags: hardhat, forks, typescript

I have an `ALCHEMY_MAINNET_RPC_URL` environment that is of type string. I can verify it as such with:

```js
const ALCHEMY_MAINNET_RPC_URL = process.env.ALCHEMY_MAINNET_RPC_URL || ''
console.log(typeof (ALCHEMY_MAINNET_RPC_URL))
```

And I get the output `string`.

In my config, I have a network setup as such:

```js
const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
    defaultNetwork: 'hardhat',
    networks: {
        mainnet_fork: {
            chainId: 1,
            forking: {
                url: ALCHEMY_MAINNET_RPC_URL,
            }
        },
```

When trying to add this to my `hardhat.config.ts`, I keep getting the following error:

```
Error HH8: There's one or more errors in your config file:

  * Invalid value undefined for HardhatConfig.networks.mainnet_fork.url - Expected a value of type string.
  
To learn more about Hardhat's configuration, please go to https://hardhat.org/config/
```

I've tried some different approaches like:

```js
const ALCHEMY_MAINNET_RPC_URL = process.env.ALCHEMY_MAINNET_RPC_URL
const ALCHEMY_MAINNET_RPC_URL = process.env.ALCHEMY_MAINNET_RPC_URL!
```

but then I get:

```
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Or the same error.

Any thoughts?

Comment: In my case, I put the `.env` file in a sub dir by mistake, move it to project root dir, then it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not complaining about the URL inside the `forking`. You need a URL for the hardhat environment to run on:

```js
const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
    defaultNetwork: 'hardhat',
    networks: {
        mainnet_fork: {
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8545'
            chainId: 1,
            forking: {
                url: ALCHEMY_MAINNET_RPC_URL,
            }
        },
```

...or you have a `.env` file in the wrong directory.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using .env
install dotenv using

```
npm install dotenv --save
```

or as in my case, I have forgotten to add

```
require("dotenv").config();
```

on top of the hardhat.config.js file

Answer (score 1):

You have both ethereum-waffle and @nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers installed. They don't work correctly together, so please make sure you only use one.

We recommend you migrate to @nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers. Learn how to do it here: https://hardhat.org/migrate-from-waffle
Error HH8: There's one or more errors in your config file:

```
enter code here   * Invalid value undefined for HardhatConfig.networks.mumbai.url - Expected a value of type string.
```

- Invalid account: #0 for network: mumbai - Expected string, received undefined

To learn more about Hardhat's configuration, please go to https://hardhat.org/config/

This error occur due to dotenv package and same time we forgot to take .env file on same directory.

Comment: https://hardhat.org/migrate-from-waffle  this link is no more valid, leads to 404.

Answer (score 0):

✅ Ansewer

your `.env` file has an issue.
I think just declare your key values with `=` instead of `:`

for example in .env file

```
KEY = value
```

wrong way is  `KEY : value`

Answer (score 0):

Same problem hare,

```
  * Invalid value undefined for HardhatConfig.networks.goerli.url - Expected a value of type string.
  * Invalid account: #0 for network: goerli - Expected string, received undefined

To learn more about Hardhat's configuration, please go to https://hardhat.org/config/
```

I solve this problem by adding `require("dotenv").config()`  at the beginning of the hardhat.config file. Here

```
goerli: {
      url: process.env.RPC,
      accounts:[process.env.PRIVATE_KEY],
    },
```

Here `process.env.RPC` and `process.env.PRIVATE_KEY` is not recognized in your file without `"dotenv"` module.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a little to this question, I had the same error but my problem was that I was naming the node endpoint on the `.env` as `GOERLI="https://....."` instead of `GOERLI_URL="https://....."`.

Once changed everything worked ok.

Answer (score 0):

Add goerli after networks and before url.

```
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.4",
  networks: {
    goerli:{
      url: process.env.STAGING_ALCHEMY_KEY,
      accounts: [process.env.PRIVATE_KEY],
    }
  },
};
```

Comment: How this answers applies to the question asked? Goerli is never mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Error HH8: There's one or more errors in your config file:

- Invalid value undefined for HardhatConfig.networks.goerli.url - Expected a value of type string.
- Invalid account: #0 for network: goerli - Expected string, received undefined

To learn more about Hardhat's configuration, please go to https://hardhat.org/config/

if you get this kind of error then you just need to edit your env ...

all values have in string "example_url","Example_Api","Example_Privatekey"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are importing **dotenv** module in your hardhat config file. If not, try to add the following command at the top of **hardhat.config.js** file:

```
require("dotenv").config();
```